# How pass this element as anchor tag to javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, data-binding, anchor

This is how we are binding `Url()` model input to `knockout UI`.

```
[anchor-tag] data-bind="attr: { href: Url()"
```

Now I want to append to url few things which come from parent elements so i want to pass `"this"` element to js file.

```
[anchor-tag]  data-bind="attr: { href: myFunction1(Url(), this)"

myFunction1 = function (url, obj) {
    return url + "#" + $(obj).parents('li').attr('rankAbs');
}
```

When I do `$(obj)` in `myFunction1`, i am getting back Window object.

and i am unable to access further parent objects.

Comment: You can use data-bind="attr: { href: myFunction1(Url(), $element)". Documentation ref is http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html

Comment: May be better to wrap your logic into a custom binding, or pass 'rankAbs' from upper levels of your model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html), "$element" is the current DOM element the binding is applied to:

> This is the element DOM object (for virtual elements, it will be the
>   comment DOM object) of the current binding. This can be useful if a
>   binding needs to access an attribute of the current element. Example:

```
<div id="item1" data-bind="text: $element.id"></div>
```

In your case:

```
[anchor-tag]  data-bind="attr: { href: myFunction1(Url(), $element)"
```

If in your function you are taking parent DOM element and getting some attributes, it can be better to change your view model to provide required info.

You can also use "$parent" or "$parents" Knockout context variables, if parent model can provide required info.